# constant char* to char* in stacks

Tags: c, stack, type-conversion

i have a code here that returns an error

```
char sToken[50]=""; 
strcat(sToken, toptoken());
```

the toptoken() returns the elements of the stack and the sToken is a char array for holding a string.
after i compiled the program, the cmd displayed an error "syntax.exe has stopped working"

what i did is to change the data type of toptoken() to char*

```
strcat(sToken, (char*)toptoken());
```

but still it didn't work. The program also produced the same error.

Here is the code snippet for toptoken();

```
struct node{
   char* token;
   char* lexeme;
   struct node *ptr;
}*top,*top1,*temp;
char* toptoken(){

   return (top->token);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What *exactly* does `toptoken` return? Where does `sToken` come from? Please provide a complete example.

Comment: Is that really supposed to be a comma, not a semicolon, between the declaration of `sToken[]` and the call to `strcat`?

Comment: it is a semicolon. ive already changed it

Comment: I'd say there are a few possible reasons why it's failing: top, or top->token don't point to something valid or the string returned by toptoken() is too large to fit in the sToken array.

Comment: You need to provide the code where `top->token` is set. It looks very likely that is invalid.

Comment: The error can be anywhere in your program. What makes you think it's the fragment you have posted is responsible for it?